# Как включить вспышку в смартфоне?

Tags: javascript

Возник такой вопрос: возможно ли средствами JavaScript включить/выключить вспышку в смартфоне? Хочу добавить этот функционал на свой сайт. В Интернете не нашел четкого ответа.

*Заранее спасибо!*

Comment: В браузере скорее всего никак (нет API). Иначе все бы это использовали) В приложениях можно (с фреймворками по типу ionic или NativeScript) – но там своё API, которое напрямую к системе обращается, и таких вопросов бы явно не возникло))

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921704/turn-on-off-mobile-flashlight-from-a-web-browser

Comment: Я б после такого на данный сайт не заходил бы больше ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе инфамации по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921704) (ссылается на [stackoverflow.com/questions/37848494](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848494)), которую привёл @EzioMercer.

Можно но есть ограничения:

- cайт должен иметь https
- только Chrome
- только Android

```js
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        facingMode: "environment" // задняя камера. Фронтальная - user
    },
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
    let track = stream.getVideoTracks().pop();

    // непосредственно включение фонарика
    track.applyConstraints({
        advanced: [{torch: true}],
    });
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!